# How can I draw Letters in 3js/threeJS easily?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have to draw letters using 3JS.

Previously I have drawed objects in Canvas with beziercurves, using a website that helped do them with the mouse.

Is there such a tool for the same job in 3JS?

I can't seem to find anything. And drawing them manually in code just seems a waste of time.

I've searched everywhere for it but nothing.

I'm using Spline Curves btw...

```
    curve = new THREE.SplineCurve( [
    new THREE.Vector2( -90, 50),
    new THREE.Vector2( -150, 0),
    new THREE.Vector2( -130, 50),
    
]);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to put text along a spline?

Comment: Check out this add on. It works with Three.js  https://github.com/protectwise/troika/tree/master/packages/troika-3d-text

Answer (score 1):

https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Creating-text
Gives different ways to draw text.

You can use TextGeometry:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);
  camera.position.z = 10;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
  loader.load('https://unpkg.com/three@0.77.0/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function(font) {
    var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry('Hello World', {
      font: font,
      size: 1,
      height: 1
    });
    geometry.center();
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
  });

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r99/three.js" integrity="sha256-QlZjRhqOlDukXFfprbpsdrDQws7TtQdTGDh7F7Q3310=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: that's a good base but...

As I'm doing it I feel like I have to use splines for the whole thing. So I can't just use the documentation... 

So basically I have to use splines from left to right to draw a word.

Should I do multiple functions? How can I call multiples letters using splines only?

Then once I do the splines, I have to make it "3d" use depth and stuff like that